# Affix não para corretamente no rodapé

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Estou tentando criar um Affix com o Bootstrap mas estou tendo problemas para ele parar corretamente no rodapé.

Ele buga, e a classe `.affix-bottom` não fica aplicada corretamente. Quando passo do *offset bottom* rodando o scroll ele para normal, mas  se eu desço arrastando a barra de rolagem ele não para.

E também na hora de voltar para cima, ele fica aplicado o `position:relative` que impossibilita a classe `.affix` de funcionar corretamente na subida.

**[Demonstração](http://www.bootply.com/FrAGifRvdf)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tinha um erro no css, corrigido `.affix-bottom.{` para `.affix-bottom{`.

**[Corrigido](http://www.bootply.com/uBVuC3Te95)**

**PS.: Desculpe a falta de atenção**, mas eu fiquei a manhã toda brigando com essa "bobeira".